# PL-SQL how to inner join twice on the same table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to make a query that joins a table twice for language purpose.

But SQL Developer always throws an error

> Invalid Identifier in the SELECT

when I try to use the ALIAS of my table (table2 is invalid)

```
SELECT
    table1.code Code,
    table2.descr DescrFr,
    table3.descr_en DescrEn
FROM
    main_table table1
INNER JOIN 
    descr_table table2 ON table1.code = table2.code 
                       AND table2.lang = 'fr'
INNER JOIN
    descr_table table3 ON table1.code = table3.code 
                       AND table3.lang = 'en'
```

I didn't find anything helpful for my case that could teach me what's wrong with my query.

**EDIT**

Tested asked by user but resulted with this error

Erreur SQL : ORA-00904: "TABLE3"."code" : identificateur non valide

```
SELECT 
   table1.code AS Code, 
   table2.descr AS DescrFr, 
   table3.descr AS DescrEn 
FROM main_table table1 
INNER JOIN descr_table table2 ON (table1.code = table2.code) 
INNER JOIN descr_table table3 ON (table1.code = table3.code) 
WHERE (table2.lang = 'fr' AND table3.lang = 'en');
```

**Answer**

The result is a facepalm... the initial query is working.. i was just using the wrong column name in the descr_table...

Comment: It seems odd to me that you would join twice when you have two columns in the `descr_table` one `descr` and one `descr_en`. OR... do you not actually have a column in `descr_table` named `descr_en` and that is causing the error?

Comment: i have 2 row for FR and for EN language so i need to get in 1 row Code, FR DESC and EN DESC because in the DB its in 2 row atm

Comment: Do you have 2 columns: descr and descr_en?

Comment: My point though is that you are referencing a specific column in `descr_table` in your `SELECT` clause. You say `table3.descr_en` Do you have a column in your `descr_table` called `descr_en`? Perhaps it would be prudent to share some sample data and desired results. It feels a bit like diffusing a bomb with blindfolds on.

Comment: In the DB there is 2 row (1 for FR and 1 for EN language) but i need to get a query that make them in a single row  Code, FR_DESC, EN_DESC

Comment: (1) Your error message is from Oracle, not SQL Server.  (2) The error message implies that the `code` column doesn't exist, so please show the full table definition for `descr_table` *(using `describe` or something similar, not by copying it by hand - so avoiding assumptions, typos, etc)*.

Comment: Damn, i've wrote T_SQL but it's PL-SQL ... sorry i'm usually a SQL Server user... typo, i changed title and tags

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the version you are using but I guess you could try `SELECT table1.code AS Code,...`. And I would prefer not using so much `INNER JOIN` in your sql query rather would use at least one `RIGHT JOIN or LEFT JOIN` because you need to have a "main table" which has the highest priority.

AND of course there is something wrong I guess.
so your code would be fine in this way:

```
SELECT 
    table1.code AS Code, 
    table2.descr AS DescrFr, 
    table3.descr_en AS DescrEn 
FROM 
    main_table AS table1 
INNER JOIN 
    descr_table AS table2 ON (table1.code = table2.code) 
INNER JOIN 
    descr_table table3 ON (table1.code = table3.code) 
WHERE 
    (table2.lang = 'fr' AND table3.lang = 'en')
```

Comment: Your query doesnt work because the AS Keyword doesnt work in ALIAS for table in TSQL but even if i remove them the query still doesnt work.

Comment: Can you share the error message with me please?

Comment: THis is basically the identical query as the OP already posted - I don't see any reason why this would work (if the OP's query doesn't work)

Comment: edited my original post, i dont know if it can help because we are writting the same query but differently

Answer (score -1):

I'd avoid the double join altogether.

- and ***never*** use aliases such as `table1`

This could be...

```
SELECT
  main.Code,
  descr.DescrFr,
  descr.DescrEn
FROM
  main_table  main
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    code,
    MAX(CASE WHEN lang = 'fr' THEN descr END)   AS DescrFr,
    MAX(CASE WHEN lang = 'en' THEN descr END)   AS DescrEn
  FROM
    descr_table
  WHERE
    lang IN ('fr', 'en')
  GROUP BY
    code
)
  descr
    ON descr.code = main.code
```

*(And even then, from your description, you don't even need the outer join as the `code` exists in the `descr_table`.)*

Comment: You should know that most user can't share the DB description so I modified the query as needed to keep the idea behind it (modified table-name, alias-name and column-name)

Comment: the query doesnt work either, it tell me descr is an invalid identifier in the ON clause

Comment: @vince And you ***still*** haven't provided the table definition for `descr_table`.  As per my comment on your question...  `(2) The error message implies that the [code] column doesn't exist, so please show the full table definition for [descr_table] (using describe or something similar, not by copying it by hand - so avoiding assumptions, typos, etc).`  It's completely clear to me that the column `code` simply ***does not exist*** in the table `descr_table`.

Comment: facepalm... you are right... the column i've tried to use is named differently than what i've though...